# acceder a un botón que se creó dinámicamente con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Tengo este botón que se creó al traer un objeto guardado en un archivo JSON.
Necesito asignarle una función que se active al hacer click en dicho botón. ¿Cómo puedo acceder al mismo? Muestro a continuación el código.

```javascript
$.get(URLGET, function (respuesta, estado) {
  if (estado === "success") {
    let misPromos = respuesta;
    for (const promo of misPromos) {
      $(".container-cards").append(`<div>
        <h3>${promo.promName}</h3>
        <p> ${promo.description}</p>
        <button class="btn-search danger transparent" id="${promo.id}">Reservar</button>
      </div>`);
    }
  }
  // counter= false; // por qué siguen saliendo las cards });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo usando su `id` como parámetro de búsqueda de jQuery y, posteriormente, agregando un manipulador para el evento "click" con [`jQuery.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$("#" + promo.id).on( "click", () => {
    /* Haz lo que quieras aquí */
});
```

O, lo que es lo mismo, usando [`jQuery.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/):

```
$("#" + promo.id).click(() => {
    /* Haz lo que quieras aquí */
});
```

De modo que tu código quedaría como muestro a continuación:

```
$.get(URLGET, function (respuesta, estado) {
  if (estado === "success") {
    let misPromos = respuesta;
    for (const promo of misPromos) {
      $(".container-cards").append(`<div>
        <h3>${promo.promName}</h3>
        <p> ${promo.description}</p>
        <button class="btn-search danger transparent" id="${promo.id}">Reservar</button>
      </div>`);
      /* Aquí creamos el manipulador del evento "click" */
      $("#" + promo.id).on("click", () => {
        /* Haz lo que quieras aquí */
      });
    }
  }
  // counter= false; // por qué siguen saliendo las cards });
});
```

---

También puedes hacerlo prescindiendo de jQuery con el siguiente código usando [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```
document.getElementById(promo.id).addEventListener("click", () => {
    /* Hacer aquí lo que quieras */
});
```

O también usando la propiedad [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick):

```
document.getElementById(promo.id).onclick = () => {
    /* Hacer aquí lo que quieras */
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Con jquery puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$('body').on('click','.clase_de_un_elemento', function(){//escuchar acciones a elementos que se agregaron despues de cargado el documento, tambien sirve para los ya existentes
    //codigo a ejecutar
});
```

Para esto accedemos al documento con $('body') y definimos que es lo que se desea escuchar en este caso un click esto dentro de $(document).ready()